# Math function to find the biggest multiple of a number within a range

Tags: python, math

I want to know if there is a math expression that I can use to find this relation between two numbers.

Some examples of the input and expected output are below:

```
Input    Multiple   Result
4        3          3
6        3          6
8        3          6
4        4          4
12       4          12
16       5          15
```

Also, the expressions below from Wolfram Alpha show me the expected result but since they don't expand on the explanation on how to do it I can't learn from them...

[Biggest multiple of 4 from 10](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=biggest%20multiple%20of%204%20from%2010)

[Biggest multiple of 4 from 12](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=biggest%20multiple%20of%204%20from%2012)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can employ modulo for this. For example, to calculate the biggest multiple of 4 that is less or equal than 13:

```
13 % 4 = 1
13 - 1 = 12
```

in python, that could look like this:

```
def biggest_multiple(multiple_of, input_number):
    return input_number - input_number % multiple_of
```

So you use it as:

```
$ biggest_multiple(4, 9)
8
$ biggest_multiple(4, 12)
12
```

Comment: incorporated your answer into mine, so that the effect of `//` and `%` can be seen next to each other!

Comment: let's copy all answers into all answers. it's gonna be great!

Answer (score 8):

try with `//` and `%` operators!

for `//`, you would do

```
Result = (Input // Multiple) * Multiple
```

This way you get how many times Multiple Fits into Input - this number is then multiplied with the Multiple itself and therefore gives you the expected results!

EDIT: how to do it with modulo `%`?

```
Result = Input - (Input % Multiple)
```

taken from [MCO's answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52060049/7856505)

Comment: about the rejected edit: i think one of us is having a brain outage. shouldn't `Input` always be less than `Multiple`? which would make this answer return 0?

example with 10 and 3: `(3 // 10) * 3 = 0`

Comment: that's why I rejectd the edit! 10 is the input, and you wanna know the biggest possible multiple of 3 in 10. so you go (10//3)*3 which gives you 9 - the correct answer.

Comment: yep, so it was me. i expected `Multiple` to be the range (10). <s>totally gonna blame the language barrier</s>

Comment: nobody's perfect :-) but thanks for challenging though, made me think very hard about it!

Comment: What if the multiple is 0? think of extremes

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I would do it:

```
return int(input / multiple) * multiple
```

It truncates the division so that you get an integer, which you can multiply.

Comment: to avoid casting to int, you just use // like in my proposed answer! but same simple algorithm :-)

Comment: @Cut7er Casting is a preference of mine, since I like seeing the casts in more complex functions/lines. It helps remind me what's going on :)

Comment: What will happen if multiple is 0?

Comment: @mad_ "This exception is left as an exercise to the reader". It would be a ZeroDivisionError.

Answer (score 2):

This can be trivial but damn easy to understand. To take into account if multiple is negative or zero

```
Multiple=[3,3,3,4,4,5,0,-5]
Input=[4,6,8,4,12,16,1,8]
Result=[]
for input,multiple in zip(Input,Multiple):
    if(multiple):
        Result.append((range(multiple,input+1,abs(multiple)))[-1])
    else:
        Result.append(0)
print(Result)
```

Output:

```
[3, 6, 6, 4, 12, 15, 0, 5]
```

Comment: While this is the most trivial answer it may have the largest overhead, especially with larger inputs (unless `max` is smart enough to know that a `range` object is sorted, which I highly doubt)

Comment: @DeepSpace Yeah, max was the overhead. Replaced it with [-1] we do not need max in sorted inputs for max. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are timecomparisons of the previous methods.

Note that I'm keeping the divisor as 6 (as is my use case). In addition, the plot has a linear - to - log axis (more complicated than the code below).

It seems  `res = val - (val % div)` is the quickest in this case.

```py
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

methods = ["res = int(val / div) * div",
           "res = (val // div) * div",
           "res = val - (val % div)"]
div = 6
repeats = 100_000
times = [[] for method in methods]

for val in range(0, 1_000):
    for i in range(len(methods)):
        duration = timeit.timeit(setup=f"val={val}; div={div}", stmt=methods[i])
        times[i].append(duration)

for i, trend in enumerate(times):
    plt.plot(list(range(0, 1_000)), trend, label=methods[i])

plt.xlabel('Value "v"')
plt.ylabel('Duration (s)')
plt.title("Method comparison;")
plt.show()
```

[image: Matplotlib Plot of Time]